# AWS Lambda recursive, can't success to do it right

Tags: node.js, for-loop, while-loop, aws-lambda, switch-statement

Hi I would like to recall lambda function when context.getRemaingTimeInMillis() is less the 1 min. So I have this:

```
for (actions of commandArray) {
 while (context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() > 60000) {
    switch(actions.action) {
       case: do something
       case: etc..
    }
  }
}
let done = then I check if I am satisfied with results
if (done){
save results 
} else {
sendSQS(recurseMessage);
}
```

I  get infinite loop (ofcourse), but I tried :

```
for (actions of commandArray) {
if (context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() > 60000) {
    switch(actions.action) {
       case: do something
       case: etc..
    }
  } else { 
     break;
}
let done = then I check if I am satisfied with results
if (done){
save results 
} else {
sendSQS(recurseMessage);
}
```

but it acts weird, it never exists a case (long session case) and my Lambda doesnt get timed out it finishes fit 230 iterations for example and I have Lambda time set to 3 mins.

Comment: So, what are you asking exactly?

Comment: if you have any idea. But i think fixed it with if(context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() > 60000) inside evrery for loop inside the cases;